# Firefox add-on to display all tabs in one page

Tags: firefox

Do we have an add-on in Firefox that will put all tabs in one page and under each other?

I have a lot of tabs and I want to see them all in one page. Something that does what Re-pagination or pagezipper does with tabs. Re-pagination/pagezipper is an add-on in Google Chrome and Firefox that will put a lot or multiple pages in one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scrapbook X](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook-x/) did what I wanted. It combined the pages that I wanted to put together but if I see something that does more and combines pages with more pages or combines a lot of pages in one page, I will show it here.

Answer (score 2):

If you pretend to manage all the tabs quickly, then you can use the [Tile tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tile-tabs/) add-on

When you've made a tabs composition (horizontal or another one), if you select a tab and hit the F2 key the layout will be switched to see the full page for the tab.

On the other hand, if you want to save a entire page with all the tabs, then the [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) add-on comes on handy. With ScrapBook you can save locally all the opened tabs (Scrapbook -> 'Save all the tabs'). After that, in the ScrapBook options, you go to 'Combine Wizard' and select all the downloaded pages for combining and the order to generate an unique page for them.

Cheers

Comment: Scrapbook did what I want a little but when I combine the tabs it only showed some of the tabs and some were duplicated. I've seen Tile tabs before but I wanted a combination of all pages in one page but I might start using it.

Comment: I think [Scrapbook X](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook-x/) combined 8 tabs but I don't know if it will combine more.